# Youtube-DL file download live progress

Tags: php, ajax, video, youtube, ffmpeg

I am using the [YoutubeDL library](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl) in a project. My environment is based on WINDOWS with XAMPP as the webserver boundle (apache,php,mysql,etc). I am using the youtube-dl.exe file to download the video and then use ffmpeg.exe to convert the video to an MP3 audio file.

At the moment, I have an issue related to programming: I want to show live a progressbar while the video is downloaded with the youtube-dl.exe file. This exe creates a log file, that is updated while the video is downloaded. So my approach on this was to create a PHP file, that opens, parses the log file and get's the progress percent, and sends it as a json encoded value to an AJAX function that is called every 100MS. Indeed, if the video is too large, there will be a very high ammount of data while polling the PHP file to get the progress state. And sometimes, the browser either crashes or freezes because of this ajax polling.

My question is: is there any better approach to do this with PHP/AJAX? Rathar than poll the file every 100MS, or 50MS?

Comment: Rosh can you please share how you managed to print on a file the download progress? im on windows and xampp too but i tried popen ytdl and then write a txt but for some reason i cant get anything inside the file.. Can you please share your approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Poll only every second and animate the progress bar.